# Order hierarchy members by natural order

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

I have a SSAS cube with the following dimensions:

```
Time
    DayName <- Hierarchy

Item
    Description <- Hierarchy
```

In the `Measures` dimension I have a measure for the `LostAmount`.

I want to query the cube so that I can get the sum of lost amount per week day. The following query works:

```
select
    except(Time.DayName.members, {Time.DayName.[All]}) on 0,
    except(Item.Description.members, {Item.Description.All}) on 1
from Cube
```

But when returning the results the order of columns is not the natural order of week days (i.e. the order of columns is `Friday, Monday, Sunday etc`).

[image: Query results.]

How can I have the result columns in the natural order of week days i.e. `Monday, Tuesday etc.`?

Comment: this is strange `except(Time.DayName.members, {Time.DayName.[All]})` why not just do `Time.DayName.DayName` ?

Comment: @whytheq, because I didn't know you can do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your screenshot, the days in the Time.DayName level **are** being sorted in natural order: it's the alphabetical order of the member names.

There's no way that SSAS can "know" what the order you want is.  I'd suggest adding a Key column to this dimension, numbering the days in the order you want, and changing the dimension attribute's OrderBy property to Key rather than Name.  (Perhaps you already do have a key: but OrderBy=Name will naturally order the members by their name).

**Addition:** There is a dimension attribute Type property in SSAS, which can be set to "Day of Week" - but I've never used it, and don't know whether it would correctly detect that your member names are the names of weekdays.  Or whether it will order your week starting on the "right" day that you want to start your week from.  You could try setting it and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 1):

While it's definitely better to change the cube structure, sometimes it's not a feasible option. In such cases, it has to be handled inside `MDX` code(which is slower). Below is one way.

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.weekdaynumber AS  
    CASE Time.DayName.CURRENTMEMBER 
        WHEN "Monday" THEN 1
        WHEN "Tuesday" THEN 2
        WHEN "Wednesday" THEN 3
        WHEN "Thursday" THEN 4
        WHEN "Friday" THEN 5
        WHEN "Saturday" THEN 6
        WHEN "Sunday" THEN 7
    END

SELECT 
  Order
  (
    Except
    (
      Time.DayName.MEMBERS
     ,{Time.DayName.[All]}
    )
   ,Measures.weekdaynumber
  ) ON 0
 ,Except
  (
    [Item].[Description].MEMBERS
   ,{[Item].[Description].[All]}
  ) ON 1
FROM [Cube];
```

Comment: (upped) I like this measure

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for the ordering issue by defining additional members on the `Measures` dimension and outputting them in the desired order:

```
with
member Measures.Monday as 
    sum(Time.DayName.&[Monday], Measures.LostValue)
member Measures.Tuesday as
    sum(Time.DayName.&[Tuesday], Measures.LostValue)
member Measures.Wednesday as
    sum(Time.DayName.&[Wednesday], Measures.LostValue)
member Measures.Thursday as 
    sum(Time.DayName.&[Thursday], Measures.LostValue)
member Measures.Friday as
    sum(Time.DayName.&[Friday], Measures.LostValue)
member Measures.Saturday as
    sum(Time.DayName.&[Saturday], Measures.LostValue)
member Measures.Sunday as
    sum(Time.DayName.&[Sunday], Measures.LostValue)
select
{
    Measures.Monday,
    Measures.Tuesday,
    Measures.Wednesday,
    Measures.Thursday,
    Measures.Friday,
    Measures.Saturday,
    Measures.Sunday
} on 0,
except(Item.Description.members, {Item.Description.[All]}) on 1
from [Cube]
```